# Scrollbar appears when centering vertically and horizontally, can't get rid of it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3.0.3, I'm attempting to center both horizontally and vertically a div with a hard-coded width and height. The JSFiddle has the latest code in it, also reported here to be consistent with SO's rules regarding JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/alex_kurilin/pNYg9/

The HTML:

```
<div class="text-center full-height">
    <div class="inline full-height">
        <div class="fake-table full-height">
            <div class="fake-table-cell full-height">
                <div class="content fake-table">
                    <div class="fake-table-cell">foobar</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fake-table {
    display: table;
}
.fake-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

What I'm showing in the JSFiddle appears to "work", however for some reason **it adds a vertical scrollbar**. What's interesting is that changing the body's `font-size`, `font-family` and `line-height` appears to affect the scrollbar, and thus I imagine this has something to do with the `height: 100%` and the `inline-block` div.

I'd love a pointer on two on how to make this specific layout happen correctly, as I suspect I'm doing this the hard way.

Comment: Why not just set `overflow: hidden` for `html` or `body`? It seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/R4Z2c/

Comment: That's certainly an idea, I'll give you that. Still doesn't answer my question of why that'd be happening in the first place.

Comment: That's why I put it here, in the comments, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just use content element and remove others:

```
.content {
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: That's fair, as long as you can figure out the size of the grey box and you can use margins accordingly, then your solution seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Yes, you asked it for fixed size.. :)

Comment: Absolutely. I imagine that even if the size were to change, you could just change the css on the fly with js.

Comment: This seems to do the trick and folks apparently don't think there are many more options here, so I'll take your answer. Thank you!